# Pass FileStream to another program

Tags: c#, filestream, argument-passing, emulation

I would like to pass a Stream to another program as argument (to pass a path to a file that is not truly exist),

Meaning that while that program is trying to read bytes from that file, my program will generate it.

To be more clear, I would like to call a program like this:

```
notepad.exe "C:\myFile.txt"
```

And that file won't exist, and each attempt to read from that file will call my program and wait for it to respond (writing is not an issue now).

Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean passing a communication channel between them or ask your "other" program to watch for the presence of the file you specify?

Comment: Notepad _open_ the file and instead of read data from the file your program pass data to it?

Comment: Maybe you can use [memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think [Anonymous Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx)  may actually work for what you are trying to do.

You setup in your initial program, then passing the parameter to the 2nd program you can then read from it as you write to it in your 1st program.